# Outlook 2010 search field criteria: exchange folder/account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using the [Outlook query builder](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/ba021580-0f5e-4e50-96b7-91653fbedca0/) in the conditional formatting of a calendar view to highlight specific events.

Since I have multiple calendars from different exchange accounts, I only want to highlight those events in a determined exchange folder, but I can't figure out which fields to use.

I tried: `In Folder`, `Outlook Data File`.. no other seems logical.

(it seems that the conditional formatting is applied to both calendars when displayed side by side).